# Python pillow динамический размер изображения

Tags: python, pillow

Имеется изображение, в которое должен помещаться текст. Длина текста заранее неизвестна. На данный момент длинный текст выходит за рамки окна, а нужно чтобы окно увеличивалось в соответствии с длиной текста. Как это можно реализовать?
Ниже приведен код и скрин.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
img = Image.new('RGBA', (500, 500), 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 40)
draw.text((40,40), 'Надел мужик шляпу, а та ему как раз', font=headline)
img.show()
```

[image: Скриншот изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
offset = (40, 40) # отступ текста от верхнего левого края
margins = (10, 10) # поля вокруг текста
mytext = 'Надел мужик шляпу, а та ему как раз'
headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 40)

def draw_text(text, font):
    width = font.getmask(text).getbbox()[2]
    height = font.getmask(text).getbbox()[3]

    img = Image.new('RGBA', (width+offset[0]+margins[0]*2, height+offset[1]+margins[1]*2), 'black')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text(offset, text, font=font)
    img.show()
```

проверяем:

```
draw_text(mytext, headline)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меняем параметры:

```
offset=(10, 10)
draw_text("Stackoverflow", ImageFont.truetype('times.ttf', 60))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]